# function pointer to a class member

Tags: c++, function, member

I am trying to do some like this:

```
class A {
    void *(*func)(void *);

    A(void *(*function)(void *)){
        func = function;
    }
}

class B {
    void *real_func(void *);
    A ptr;
    B()
    :ptr(&real_func)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or
>   parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member
>   function.

Someone knows how to initialize the function pointer to a function member in the same class???

Thanks!

Carlos

Comment: I highly recommend reading http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html which goes through the ins and outs of member pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Since `real_func` is not a static member function, its type cannot be `void *(*)()`. Instead, it is `void *(B::*)()` so you need to declare `func` accordingly:

```
void *(B::*func)();

// call it like this
pointer_to_b->*func();
```

If you are careful, you can also use pointer to A as the base class, but you must make sure that the pointer to A points to an instance of B:

```
void *(A::*func)();
```

At this point, however, you are mostly just replicating the functionality of virtual member functions. So I would recommend you use that instead:

```
class A {
    virtual void *func() = 0;
};

class B {
    void *func() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create B like this:

```
struct B {
    static void *real_func(void *);
    A ptr;
    B()
    :ptr(&real_func)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

A static member function acts like a regular function, so you can create a function pointer for it.

If you don't need a regular function pointer, then you can use std::function:

```
#include <functional>

struct A {
    std::function<void *(void*)> func;

    A(std::function<void *(void*)> function)
    : func(function)
    {
    }
};

struct B {
    void *real_func(void *);
    A ptr;
    B()
    : ptr(std::bind(&B::real_func,this,std::placeholders::_1))
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: But my function cannot be static! Only static functions can be associate in the initialization list?

Comment: @user2472980: only static functions can act like regular functions.

Comment: So...how i get a similar behavior to desired?

Comment: @user2472980: I've added more to my answer.

Comment: Not works for me. I use gcc 4.6 (newest stable on gentoo's portage).

Comment: @user2472980: Make sure you are using -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x.