# Function pointer as argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments

After many hours of searching I still haven't found a solution to the following problem. In my game I make use of an abstract factory which generates objects. I'm trying to pass a function made in this factory, which generates bullets, to enemy. For this I tried using a function pointer which points to factory->getBullet() and passing it with the constructor of enemy. It failed :)

```
#include "Factory.h"
int main() 
{
    Factory* f = new Factory();
    f->getEnemy(&f->getBullet);
    return 0;
}
```

**Factory.h**

```
#include "Enemy.h";
#include "Bullet.h";
class Factory {
public:
    Factory();
    virtual ~Factory();
    Enemy* getEnemy(Bullet* (*getBulletPtr)(int));
    Bullet* getBullet(int damage);
};
```

**Factory.cpp**

```
#include "Factory.h"
Factory::Factory() {}
Factory::~Factory() {}

Enemy* Factory::getEnemy(Bullet* (*getBulletPtr)(int))
{return new Enemy(getBulletPtr);}

Bullet* Factory::getBullet(int damage)
{return new Bullet(damage);}
```

**Enemy.h**

```
#include "Bullet.h"
class Enemy
{
    private:
        Bullet* (*getBullet)(int) = NULL;
    public:
        Enemy(Bullet* (*getBulletPtr)(int));
        virtual ~Enemy();
};
```

**Enemy.cpp**

```
#include "Enemy.h"
Enemy::Enemy(Bullet* (*getBulletPtr)(int))
{
    getBullet = getBulletPtr;
    getBullet(10);
}

Enemy::~Enemy() {}
```

**Bullet.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bullet {
public:
    Bullet(int damage);
    virtual ~Bullet();
};
```

**Bullet.cpp**

```
#include "Bullet.h"
Bullet::Bullet(int damage)
{
    cout << "This is a bullet: Damage:"<< damage << endl;
}

Bullet::~Bullet()
{}
```

When I try to run this code I get the following error:

```
ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Factory::getBullet' [-fpermissive]
```

When I change

```
f->getEnemy(&f->getBullet);
```

to

```
f->getEnemy(&Factory::getBullet);
```

I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Factory::getEnemy(Bullet* (Factory::*)(int))'
```

How can I pass factory->getBullet function to my enemies.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is not the same thing as a pointer to a member function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this pointer and member function address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669182/this-pointer-and-member-function-address) or better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035902/function-pointer-to-a-class-member

Comment: Offtopic: do you really need to pass a pointer to member function to another member function of same class? Anyway, please use google next time: [How do you pass a member function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer), [Parashift: Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html). Oh, and don't forget about [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve:
 I make an Enemy and the Enemy object makes Bullet objects by themself, for this I need to pass function pointer of factory::getBullet to enemy.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a function in main, and *why are you not deleting the memory*?

Comment: This was just a test project to show my problem.
My real game project is much larger and more complex

Comment: Please verify that you want a pointer to a member versus a pointer to a function.  Check out this FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: @user3680711 pointer to free function and pointer to member function are *completely different*. Your code uses pointer to free function, it will never work to pass a member function to this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a bad design.  In general, a factory creates dynamically allocated objects **of a common theme** and returns a *base pointer* to the allocated object.

Also, most factories create the objects based on some kind of input, such as an ID value or a name or something similar:

```
struct Shape
{
  virtual const std::string& what_am_i(void) = 0;
};  // Common base class for shapes.

struct Triangle : public Shape
{
  const std::string& what_am_i(void)
  {
     const static std::string name = "triangle";
  }
};

Shape * Shape_Factory(const std::string& shape_name)
{
  Shape * p_object = NULL;
  if (shape_name == "triangle")
  {
    p_object = new Triangle;
  }
  return p_object;
}
```

You probably don't need a *factory* to create an enemy with a bullet, you could do this in a couple of statements (which cleans up your code):

```
int main(void)
{
  Bullet  b_15(15);
  Enemy   e(b_15);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above example creates an enemy with a 15 damage bullet.  This is a different concept than an enemy receiving damage from a 15 damage bullet.

I suggest something like this for applying damage:

```
struct Weapon
{
  virtual unsigned int get_damage(void) const = 0;
};

struct Bullet : public Weapon
{
  unsigned int get_damage(void) const
  { return 15;}
};

struct Player
{
  virtual void receive_damage(const Weapon& w) = 0;
};

struct Enemy : public Player
{
  unsigned int life_points;
  void receive_damage(const Weapon& w)
  {
    unsigned int damage = w.get_damage();
    if (life_points > damage)
    {
        life_points -= damage;
    }
    else
    {
        life_points = 0;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
  Bullet b;
  Enemy e;
  e.receive_damage(b);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A nice point about this design is that you can come up with different weapons, like arrows, that derive from `Weapon` and tell the `Enemy` to receive damage from the weapon.

The design expands nicely so that any `Player` (or class derived from `Player`) can receive damage from any class derived from `Weapon`.

Also notice, I have not used dynamic allocation, so I don't have any memory leak issues.  Search your favorite reference for "smart pointer", "unique_ptr" or "scoped_pointer".